# Pricing an upgrade from 2007 to 2010 for a customer?

Tags: upgrade

How would I go about pricing a 2007 > 2010 upgrade for a small business client?

What cost elements/variables/metrics to consider?

What is the typical price range?

What elements can be worked with in order to keep the pricing competitive?

Comment: Competitive with what?  Other CMS products or other consultants?

Comment: Other consultants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "typical" upgrade from 2007 to 2010.  Here are some starter questions that should point you to an answer:

- Is this 2007 WSS out of the box with no customizations or is it MOSS
  2007 heavily customized with deep ties to other systems via the BDC?
- Are they using any of the "Fab 40" templates?
- How much data is this?
- How much custom code is used?
- Do they have/use custom Site Definitions?
- What Third-Party code (i.e. Bamboo/Telerik )
- Do they have any page-level customizations?
- Is it one site or multiple sites?
- How many Content Databases?
- Are they actively using the advanced features like Excel Services and Document Management?
- Do they have custom IFilters installed for search?
- Is either environment hosted externally?  If so, you may have numerous VPN and Authentication hurdles as well
- Once they get to 2010, do they want the Ribbon interface?
- What patch level is their 2007 farm on?  i.e. you have to patch it to SP2 to even be eligible to upgrade to 2010

There are way too many variables to be able to provide an answer to your estimate question but hopefully the questions above will help get you started on understanding what all is involved.

Comment: This list is pretty comprehensive, I would only add the suggestion of running stsadm -o preupgradecheck to get a feel of the pain you're in for

Comment: Well, now there I go thinking about things. OP wants to know pricing information. You'll need to look at how many people will be involved, what are their roles, what are their rates, etc. Is this a fixed-fee or time and materials engagement?

Comment: Dammit. More thoughts. Are we upgrading/buying new hardware? And how about software licenses? SharePoint server is one thing, but are we also going from Windows Server 2003 to 2008? And SQL Server? How many users in the farm? If you currently have a per-processor license and your new server(s) have more processors, then you'll need additional licenses.

Comment: Guh, more things to consider. Do you have dev/test/qa/staging environments? Will these be upgraded as well? At this point, let me repeat what a Wise man once said: There are way too many variables to be able to provide an answer to your estimate question but hopefully the questions above will help get you started on understanding what all is involved.

Comment: All excellent points!  Perhaps I should have simply responded with the Official SharePoint Answer to Everything : "It Depends"

Comment: to piggyback on one of your points - SharePoint 2010 requires a 64-bit OS and a 64-bit Sql Server server.  It also has hardware requirements far beyond what was needed for 2007 so an upgrade usually requires the purchase of new hardware - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx